# Cumulative number of downloads on Google Code

Tags: google-code

Even though upload to Google Code will be disabled next year, it is still interesting to count the downloads.

How to get the total number of downloads (all files cumulative) of a given Google Code project?

Example: http://code.google.com/p/cmissync/downloads/list 38+39+27+...

Answer (score 1):

I just created a small script to count the downloads:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/google-code-cumulative-downloads

Just replace "cmissync" with the name of your project in the script.
The output looks like this:

```
Cumulative number of downloads:
3604
```